# Rust lifetime issue in loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How to get this example to compile without array copying or multiple calls to `b()` per iteration — `b()` has to perform some expensive parsing?

This is not the full code that I wrote, but it illustrates the problem I had. Here, `Test` is attempting to perform some kind of streaming parsing work. `c()` is the parsing function, it returns `Some` when parsing was successful. `b()` is a function that attempts to read more data from the stream when `c()` can not parse using the available data yet. The returned value is a slice into the `self.v` containing the parsed range.

```
struct Test {
    v: [u8; 10],
    index: u8,
}

impl Test {
    fn b(&mut self) {
        self.index = 1
    }

    fn c(i: &[u8]) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        Some(i)
    }

    fn a(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        loop {
            self.b();

            match Test::c(&self.v) {
                Some(r) => return r,
                _ => continue,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut q = Test {
        v: [0; 10],
        index: 0,
    };

    q.a();
}
```

When compiling, it produces the following borrow checker error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.v` is also 
borrowed as immutable
  --> <anon>:17:13
   |
17 |             self.b();
   |             ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
18 | 
19 |             match Test::c(&self.v) {
   |                            ------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

If I change `a()` to:

```
fn a(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
    loop {
        self.b();

        if let None = Test::c(&self.v) {
            continue
        }

        if let Some(r) = Test::c(&self.v) {
            return Some(r);
        } else {
            unreachable!();
        }
    }
}
```

Then it runs, but with the obvious drawback of calling the parsing function `c()` twice.

I kind of understand that changing `self` while the return value depends on it is unsafe, however, I do not understand why is the immutable borrow for `self.v` is still alive in the next iteration, when we attempted to call `b()` again.

Comment: looks like a compiler bug to me. I think the second version should not compile either (and in fact it doesn't if you remove the else branch)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, it is not a bug. Compiler can deduce that `self.b()` will not be called while second borrow of `self.v` is active, because loop unconditionally ends after this borrow is taken. If you remove else branch, then it is no longer true.

Comment: @red75prim ah you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now "Rustc can't "deal" with conditional borrowing returns". See this [comment from Gankro on issue 21906](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906#issuecomment-73296543).

It can't assign a correct lifetime to the borrow if only one execution path terminates the loop.

I can suggest this workaround, but I'm not sure it is optimal:

```
fn c(i: &[u8]) -> Option<(usize, usize)> {
    Some((0, i.len()))
}

fn a(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
    let parse_result;
    loop {
        self.b();

        match Test::c(&self.v) {
            Some(r) => {
                parse_result = r;
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    let (start, end) = parse_result;
    &self.v[start..end]
}
```

You can construct result of parsing using array indexes and convert them into references outside of the loop.

Another option is to resort to `unsafe` to decouple lifetimes. I am not an expert in safe use of unsafe, so pay attention to comments of others.

```
fn a(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
    loop {
        self.b();

        match Test::c(&self.v) {
            Some(r) => return unsafe{ 
                // should be safe. It decouples lifetime of 
                // &self.v and lifetime of returned value,
                // while lifetime of returned value still
                // cannot outlive self
                ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(r.as_ptr(), r.len())
            },
            _ => continue,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround, however, in my case the parser was written with [nom](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom) (which always returns slices), so returning length is not going to work...

Comment: @Dndx, I added another option to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the above solution using `from_raw_parts` works well.