# Cannot assign to 'node.next' because it is borrowed when reference is already out of scope

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple linked list and I ran into this problem while trying to implement remove. I can't assign to a variable because it is borrowed even though the reference is out of scope.

```
struct Node<T> {
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    value: T,
}
```

```
struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

```
fn remove(&mut self) {
    let head = self.head.as_mut().unwrap();
    if let None = head.next {
        self.head = None;
    } else {
        let mut node = head;
        loop {
            let next = node.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            if let None = next.next {
                break;
            } else {
                node = next;
            }
        }
        node.next = None;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `node.next` because it is borrowed
  --> linkedlist.rs:49:13
   |
42 |                 let next = node.next.as_mut().unwrap();
   |                            --------- borrow of `node.next` occurs here
...
49 |             node.next = None;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             assignment to borrowed `node.next` occurs here
   |             borrow later used here
```

Comment: Few things about linked lists are "simple", at least in Rust. Please read [Learn Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler bug, there's an answered question related to this issue: [Rust lifetime issue in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44108401/544707), that explains better what might be the origin of the problem:

> It can't assign a correct lifetime to the borrow if only one execution path terminates the loop.

In your example, leaking the borrowed value `next` from inside the loop (by assigning it to `node`) will cause the issue because there's a conditional loop termination, so in order to workaround this problem do not leak that borrowed value and instead re-borrow when assigning to `node`:

```rust
let mut node = head;
loop {
    let next = node.next.as_mut().unwrap();
    if let None = next.next {
        break;
    } else {
        node = node.next.as_mut().unwrap();
    }
}
node.next = None;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anler is right. I'm writing another answer, because your code is going to panic if the `LinkedList` will be empty. This is the problematic line:

```rust
let head = self.head.as_mut().unwrap();
```

If `self.head` is `None` (empty list) -> `unwrap()` will panic. Here's a working example (`loop` -> `while`):

```rust
fn remove(&mut self) {
    let head = match self.head.as_mut() {
        Some(head) => head,
        None => return,
    };

    match head.next {
        None => self.head = None,
        Some(_) => {
            let mut node = head;
            while node.next.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
                node = node.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            }
            node.next = None;
        }
    };
}
```