# Is it possible to write a function that calls BufRead::fill_buf until an interrupted error no longer occurs without using unsafe?

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker

Is it possible to write a function that calls `BufRead::fill_buf` until [`io::ErrorKind::Interrupted`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.Interrupted) no longer occurs without using unsafe?

With unsafe code, it is:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{self, BufRead},
    slice,
};

fn fill_buf_and_ignore_interrupts(reader: &mut impl BufRead) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
    let (buf_ptr, buf_len) = loop {
        match reader.fill_buf() {
            Ok(buf) => (buf.as_ptr(), buf.len()),
            Err(e) => {
                if e.kind() != io::ErrorKind::Interrupted {
                    return Err(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Ok(unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(buf_ptr, buf_len) })
}
```

If I try to `return` or `break` `Ok(buf)`, I get an error from the borrow checker:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*reader` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:15
  |
6 | fn fill_buf_and_ignore_interrupts(reader: &mut impl BufRead) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
  |                                           - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
7 |     let (buf_ptr, buf_len) = loop {
8 |         match reader.fill_buf() {
  |               ^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
9 |             Ok(buf) => return Ok(buf),
  |                               ------- returning this value requires that `*reader` is borrowed for `'1`
```

I have tried to replace the loop with recursion, but the error stays. I have also tried to use `#![feature(nll)]`, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in safe Rust today for the loop to return a reference to `fill_buf`'s return. (At least I hit my head against this for a while before giving up.)

But...you could just call `fill_buf` an extra time. If the buffer is already filled, the call should return `Ok`, and I'd expect the cost to be minimal. (Maybe inlining and optimization will eliminate it entirely.) If that's not true, the underlying `BufRead` implementation is bad.

I just did something similar in a `BufRead` adapter that skips escape bytes (looping over the underlying stream's `fill_buf` when the current chunk has no more non-escape bytes to pass along).

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

pub fn fill_buf_and_ignore_interrupts(reader: &mut impl BufRead) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
    while let Err(e) = reader.fill_buf() {
        if e.kind() != io::ErrorKind::Interrupted {
            return Err(e);
        }
    }
    reader.fill_buf()
}
```

Pay no attention to the other answer that says you must never call `fill_buf` without `consume`. It's wrong. You should simply expect that if you call `fill_buf` again without calling `consume` first, the stream will be at the same position. You only need to call `consume` when you want the stream to advance. (And I don't know how you could end up with the nonsense idea that you should call `consume` after `fill_buf` returns error...)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot, and neither should you want to for reasons highlighted below (they have nothing to do with the reference return or `unsafe`). [`fill_buf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) does not work the way you think it does, due to one important caveat from the doc:

> Returns the contents of the internal buffer, filling it with more data
>   from the inner reader **if it is empty**.

In other words, a subsequent call to `fill_buf` without `consume` will be a no-op if the trait is implemented properly and follows the contract stated in the doc. As such, doing one without the other is fraught with risk if you forget that requirement anywhere in anything that calls `fill_buf`.

Two solutions:

- If you're reading to the end of a stream (which is what a `BufReader` does in quite a few other languages), just `BufRead::read_to_end()`, `BufRead::read_line()` or `BufRead::read_until()`. If you can identify a delimiter, `read_until` can be easily be worked into an iterable structure
- If you are trying to **peek** at the data and possibly wait for more, you'll need to implement your own trait. This is not a frequent need as most people trying to peek into a stream are looking for a `Pattern` or a single byte, which `BufRead` covers.

As a quick summary, `fill_buf` does not do what you think it does, and you should not need to call it more than once without consuming the internal state of the buffer. If you are not trying to do this, then the lower-level methods of `BufRead` are not the tool for the job.

Comment: `BufRead` isn't useful for `fill_buf` - `BufRead` is useful for `lines()`, `read_line()` and `read_until()`, which it enables.

Comment: So you're telling me that there is a purpose in reading a single arbitrarily-sized chunk of bytes from a `BufRead` without subsequently `consume`ing it, when even `Read` provides [this very behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) on `read()` without requiring a recursive reference to an internal buffer, to the point that you need a `BufRead` and `unsafe` to implement [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=828129ffd4acdd2ea201405db486b37e)?

Comment: There are places for `BufRead`. This is evidently not one of them.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You take a `BufRead`, you `fill_buf()` *once* with an arbitrary amount of data from a *single* internal read (because, once it succeeds, you break the loop without even checking if `buf.len()` > old length), retrying if you get `Interrupted`, and then you reassemble the slice. That's your code, correct?

Comment: Correct. It is just `fill_buf()` which never returns `Interrupted` error.

Comment: so... how is that different to the `Read` code snippet?

Comment: Uh... But that they have in common? Completely different signature, completely different behavior. `fill_buf()` does not consume a single byte from reader, but `read()` does.

Comment: One thing at a time. Regarding signature, which part of `pub trait BufRead: Read` did you miss?

Comment: Regarding `fill_buf()` not consuming anything yet returning a reference to it without doing the appropriate housekeeping without `consume()`, how is that something you would *want* in an implementation of a function? Plus, that's not even true. `BufRead` itself consumes bytes from the inner reader and allocates to itself.

Comment: This is a non sequitur. The question doesn't say "I want to use bytes returned by `fill_buf` without calling `consume`" (I agree that wouldn't make sense). The questioner's code snippet is only calling `fill_buf` again in the `ErrorKind::Interrupted` case, in which no bytes were returned, much less used.

Answer (score -2):

I have found the answer here: [Rust lifetime issue in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104519/rust-lifetime-issue-in-loop/44108401#44108401)

> Rustc can't "deal" with conditional borrowing returns

So, for now, unsafe in such case is the only answer.